# Dynamically adding spring context configuration at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, junit

In spring/junit you can load application context files using `@ContextConfiguration` such as

```
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:a.xml", "classpath:b.xml"})
```

I have a requirement where if I see a special annotation on a test class then add another XML context file dynamically. For example:

```
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:a.xml", "classpath:b.xml"})
@MySpecialAnnotation 
class MyTest{
...
}
```

In the above example I would look for `@MySpecialAnnotation` and add `special-context.xml` also. What is the best way to do this? I have looked at this for a while and it seems like sub-classing my own `ContextLoader` which is one of the parameters to `@ContextConfiguration` is the best approach? Is this correct? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic. An Annotation is static, it does not change at runtime?

Comment: Obviously that is the problem I am trying to solve. I'd like to dynamically add a new context to the list of files that spring loads.

Comment: But what is the meaning of that annotation? What should trigger the "now add context x"?

Comment: @Ralph everything is executed in the spring and junit environment. I am asking if there is a handle or callback where I can control this. What should trigger the callback is my question.

Comment: can you provide an actual requirement that describes the reason behind it? I believe what you are trying to do can be solved without changing applicationContext's guts on the fly.

Comment: Its complicated but what I am trying to achieve is to create a testing platform for our company. We want to be able to enable features at runtime so that other teams can use. For example, we want to leverge using DBUnit if someone wants to use it. But we don't always want to load DBUnit if we don't need it. Does this help?

Comment: I guessing using the word runtime is misleading. What I am trying to do is other teams to create their own annotation with where others can just include in their test cases. This annotation can run some stuff before the test and after but also needs to have its own context loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the best solution is to create my own [ContextLoader](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html). I did this by extending the abstract one.

```
public class MyCustomContextListener extends GenericXmlContextLoader implements ContextLoader {
    @Override
    protected String[] generateDefaultLocations(Class<?> clazz) {
        List<String> locations = newArrayList(super.generateDefaultLocations(clazz));
        locations.addAll(ImmutableList.copyOf(findAdditionalContexts(clazz)));
        return locations.toArray(new String[locations.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] modifyLocations(Class<?> clazz, String... locations) {
        List<String> files = newArrayList(super.modifyLocations(clazz, locations));
        files.addAll(ImmutableList.copyOf(findAdditionalContexts(clazz)));
        return files.toArray(new String[files.size()]);
    }

    private String[] findAdditionalContexts(Class<?> aClass) {
        // Look for annotations and return 'em
    }
}
```

Comment: How to add and create a test case for the same (not suite but need a test case) to cross check and validate ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can make use of Spring 3.1 [Profiles](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) to achieve this.

If you put the beans defined in special-context.xml into a profile called special you can activate the special profile using @Profile("special) on your class.

This would remove the need for your special annotation entirely.